# TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len() when get dataframe length

Tags: python, pandas

The test.csv likes this:

```
device_id,upload_time
12345678901,2020-06-01 07:40:20+00:00
123456,2020-06-01 07:40:40+00:00
123456,2020-06-01 07:41:00+00:00
123456,2020-06-01 07:41:02+00:00
123456,2020-06-01 07:41:04+00:00
123456,2020-06-01 07:41:08+00:00
12345678901,2020-06-01 07:41:10+00:00
12345678901,2020-06-01 07:41:18+00:00
12345678901,2020-06-01 07:41:20+00:00
,2020-06-01 07:41:24+00:00
,2020-06-01 07:41:40+00:00
12345678901,2020-06-01 07:42:00+00:00
12345678901,2020-06-01 07:42:20+00:00
12345678901,2020-06-01 07:42:22+00:00
12345678901,2020-06-01 07:42:24+00:00
12345678901,2020-06-01 07:42:26+00:00
12345678901,2020-06-01 07:42:28+00:00
12345678901,2020-06-01 07:42:40+00:00
1234,2020-06-01 07:43:00+00:00
1234,2020-06-01 07:43:12+00:00
```

dataframe:
[image]

You can convert deviceid to `int` or `str`, no problem.
I use this code to get new dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'test.csv', encoding='utf-8', parse_dates=[1])
df = df[pd.notnull(df['device_id'])] #Delete rows where device_id is null.
a = df[df['device_id'].map(len)!=11] #Get data whose device_id length is not 11.
b = df[df['device_id'].map(len)==11] #Get data whose device_id length is 11.
```

But the error message is:

> TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Where is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the input file that you have specified, it looks like the `device_id` column is considered as a `float` datatype for some reason, although all values are `int` type. You will face an issue while trying to calculate the length due to this:

Example:

```
len('12345') 
#will give you len = 5, which is the correct length
```

whereas,

```
len('12345.0') 
#will give you len = 7, which is wrong since it considers the decimal point too
```

So it is better to convert your datatype to `int` and then perform the length check on the `str` version of the `int` column as below:

Reference:

1. The len argument may be a sequence (string, tuple or list) or a
   mapping (dictionary).
   https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len
2. Before calling the len function, you should verify if the argument
   is one of this type. You can call the method isinstance() to verify
   it. Take a look on how to use it.
   https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance

So try this,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'sample.csv', parse_dates=[1])
df = df[pd.notnull(df['device_id'])] #Delete rows where device_id is null.

#Convert to int
df['device_id'] = df['device_id'].astype(float).astype(int)

#len function cannot be computed on an int column directly. You should convert to str and then compute len
a = df[df['device_id'].astype(str).map(len)!=11]
b = df[df['device_id'].astype(str).map(len)==11]
```

Comment: Hi,when I use your code,the error message is `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12345678901.0'`

Comment: @CR7 - I don't seem to get this. Can you tell me which python version are you using and on which statement is this error thrown?

Comment: I use python3.7,error message is:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/test1.py", line 7, in <module>
    df['device_id'] = df['device_id'].astype(int)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 547, in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12345678901.0'`

Comment: Try the updated code. I think it should be something with the data that is outside of the sample data that you have provided in the question

Comment: It may be what you said, there is no problem when I change to a new csv.

Answer (score 0):

Below code would help you

Converting the float value into string will help to know the number of digits.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'test.csv', encoding='utf-8', parse_dates=[1])

# to remove the null(nan)
df = df.dropna()
or 
df = df[df['device_id'].isnull()==False]
or
df = df[df['device_id'].isna()==False]

a = df[df['device_id'].astype(str).map(len)!=11]
b = df[df['device_id'].astype(str).map(len)==11]
```

another approach

```
a = df[df['device_id'].astype(str).str.len()!=11]
b = df[df['device_id'].astype(str).str.len()==11]
```

another approach

```
a = df[df['device_id'].astype(str).apply(len)!=11]
b = df[df['device_id'].astype(str).apply(len)==11]
```

Comment: If I use your code,the rows 10 and 11 can't be removed,but in fact,the `device_id` is null(nan) in rows 10 and 11.

Comment: Hi,I have tried your code,but row 10 and 11 can't delete in dataframe `df` ,and there is still 20 rows in dataframe `a`.

Comment: If you are loading this data from an excel or CSV, row number 10 and 11 is empty cell, this code would work. by default, the dataframe would have the NaN for empty values.

Comment: added the options to drop the null rows